Lab Streaming Layer: Scaling the Data to uVolt Range
Has been using pylsl with an Emotiv EEG headset, and facing an issue comparing EDF eeg recordings with online pylsl raw data. Emotiv scales the recorded data to microvolt range when saving the recordings as EDF files, while raw pylsl data pulled from inlet seems to be in an arbitrary dynamic range units from 5 to 300s. What would be a sensible scaling factor to compare two datasets meaningfully, there also seems to be an offset as pylsl data is always positive? Went through both Emotiv LSL and LSL documentations, any ideas or help is appreciated.
